# How to read default inline onclick attribute, use the link inside and do something with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs, that have individual onclick functions. 
The functions lead to http links that open in new windows. I can not rewrite the onclick functions before generating the site because it is a third party rss feed that is being generated based on a rss file. Now i walt to keep the individual links but do something else with them.

The chronology would be the following:

1. User clicks the element that has a prewritten onclick function.
2. The onclick functions is blocked from opening in a new page.
3. The link inside the onclick function is saved for further use.
4. A HTML5 audio element gets the link as a source.

I have so far tried to overwrite the onclick function. Yet I lose the http link in the process.

```
<div class="fw-feed-item-url" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com/podcasts/podcast_eposode3.mp3' 
, '_blank')">
```

```
        $(".fw-feed-item-url").click(function(){

        var audioSrcNew = eval($('.fw-feed-item-url').attr('onclick'));
        audioElement.src = audioSrcNew;
        console.log(audioSrcNew);
        $('.fw-feed-item-url').this.attr('onclick','alert("done"); return 
        false;');

        });
```

Comment: Please add more of your code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: I added the jQuery function I was trying to implement. 
The prevention of the standard onclick function worked. yet the replacement of the audio src and reading the attribute of the standard onclick function doesnt.

Comment: Think about what `eval` actually does

Comment: I see, so eval does not just read the value but also execute it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, callbacks and event handlers should be executed in the order they were bound, and there is no way to alter that order. The code in the onclick attribute will be bound directly after creation of the element, and will thus be the first to be executed.

The only way to prevent this is to remove the attribute, either in the source or client-side by using jQuery's `.removeAttr`. So override the `onclick` event on page load like the following sample code.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var $elements =  $(".fw-feed-item-url");

    // Iterate over elements
    $elements.each(function () {

        var $elm = $(this);

        // Reference to onclick attribute value for future use
        var onClick = $elm.attr("onclick");
        console.log(onClick);

        // Remove onclick attr and bind your own click event
        $elm.removeAttr("onclick").click(function () {

            //Own code comes here
            alert("Whoa!!!! click worked!!");
        })

    });
});
```

Referenced from
[How to decide execution sequence for Javascript and Jquery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261656/how-to-decide-execution-sequence-for-javascript-and-jquery-function)